# Quasi Best-First (QBF) for opening book generation with Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search

I was reading the Chaslot papers[1,2] on opening book generation and am very confused. It seems that it will never explore more than one winning sequence. The Quasi Best-First (QBF) algorithm is described in [2] as:

> **Algorithm 1 The “Quasi Best-First” (QBF) algorithm. λ is the number of machines
> available. K is a constant. g is a game, defined as a sequence of game states.
> The function “MoGoChoice” asks MOGO to choose a move.**

```
QBF(K, λ)
while True do
  for l = 1..λ, do
    s =initial state; g = {s}.
    while s is not a final state do
      bestScore = K
      bestMove = Null
      for m in the set of possible moves in s do
        score = percentage of won games by playing the move m in s
        if score > bestScore then
          bestScore = score
          bestMove = m
        end if
      end for
      if bestMove = Null then
        bestMove = MoGoChoice(s) // lower level MCTS
      end if
      s = playMove(s, bestMove)
      g = concat(g, s)
    end while
    Add g and the result of the game in the book.
  end for
end while
```

When the book is updated with its first winning sequence, subsequent iterations will always pick that move which wins 100% of games played with that move. I can think of a number of modifications to prevent this, but I was trying to reproduce the original results as a baseline for comparison.

Some assumptions I am applying which may be incorrect:

- The outer `while True` indicates the top level - this is not actually being executed as the tree policy (selection strategy) or simulate policy (playout strategy) for some outer MCTS. (I.e., `QBF` itself is the "higher level MCTS".)
- The `initial state` is the start state of the game (i.e., an empty go board)

I'd appreciate any tips!

[1] Audouard, P., Chaslot, G., Hoock, J.-B., Perez, J., Rimmel, A., Teytaud, O., 2009. Grid Coevolution for Adaptive Simulations: Application to the Building of Opening Books in the Game of Go, in: Giacobini, M., Brabazon, A., Cagnoni, S., Di Caro, G.A., Ekárt, A., Esparcia-Alcázar, A.I., Farooq, M., Fink, A., Machado, P. (Eds.), Applications of Evolutionary Computing, Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, pp. 323–332. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-01129-0_36

[2] Chaslot, G.M.J.-B., Hoock, J.-B., Perez, J., Rimmel, A., Teytaud, O., Winands, M.H.M., 2009. Meta Monte-Carlo Tree Search for Automatic Opening Book Generation, in: Proceedings of the IJCAI’09 Workshop on General Intelligence in Game Playing Agents. Presented at the IJCAI 2009.